# Fuzzy interpretation of XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

I have found twofold treatment of `XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT` tag in Android's built-in SAX parser. Code is simple:

```
    String s; //actually contains XML
    //blah-blah
    factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
    xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    StringReader sw=new StringReader(s);
    xpp.setInput(sw);
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
               //blah-blah
        }
        else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.TEXT)
        {
               //blah-blah
        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
        {
               //blah-blah
        }
        eventType=xpp.next();
    }
```

If XML document basically looks like (String s):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates>
    <template key="Person" name="Person">
        <field key="Photo" name="Photo" type="image" hint="Press to select image"/>
    </template>
</templates>
```

With this everything works fine. But if there are some extra characters after final tag `</templates>` - here goes weird side (nature of my XML is such that sometimes there can appear some litter symbols after final tag).

For nearly all Android devices (about 90%) SAX parser ignores extra characters, but in some of devices - mostly devices with ICS - SAX parser tries to parse extra characters and crashes.

So the question is: what says XML standard? Should SAX parser try to parse extra symbols after final tag? And what anyway is `XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT` - it's either end of data or just final tag?

Comment: How do you mean 'crashes' though?

Comment: xpp.next() -says invalid character in XML document, though I was expecting that it will stop parsing after reaching final tag of XML document - and on most devices it works as described on others it doesn't

Comment: Can't understand why it tries to parse after /> of the END_DOCUMENT tag, it shall exit the loop instead. Don't believe it at all until see it myself and which device shall I take?

Comment: I was reported about such problems for SGS2 with ICS custom ROM

Comment: To be more specific we're talking about ICS Omega ROM for Samsung Galaxy S2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are non-whitespace characters after the end tag of the root element, the file is not well-formed XML and the parser is required to report this fact to the application.

Comment: Hmmm... why in this case standard Android SAX parser doesn't report?

Comment: You'll have to ask the suppliers of that parser.